# Performance of ManyToMany vs ForeignKey with filteration

Tags: postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am working on a DRF project and I have a question regarding the performance between these two choices:

First: Having a ManyToManyField in the Teacher class. So, to access the students with a Teacher, I will access the 'students' field.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ... student data ...


class Teacher(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

Second: I put the teacher as a ForeignKey in the Student class. To check students of a teacher, I will use Student.objects.filter(teacher__id=id)

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    ... teacher data ...


class Student(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Which is better overall, and especially regarding DB (PostgreSQL). Let's say I have 1M students and 100K teachers.

Note: This is just an example of my real issue. My code is much bigger than this I don't want to start copying everything since my question is just about performance. Let's say that every student can have only one teacher and a teacher can have multiple students.

Best

Comment: Which SQL table structure best represents the model? Django models are just some abstraction over such.

Comment: Perhaps consider this: what happens when a student has 4 courses, taught by 3 different teachers (one teacher teaches two courses)? What happens if the course changes teachers halfway through the term?

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for your answer.
This is just an example of my real issue. My code is much bigger than this I don't want to start copying everything. Let's say that every student can have only one teacher and a teacher can have multiple students. What is better, 1 or 2? 
Best

Comment: If a student “can have only one teacher and a teacher can have multiple students”, then only *one* of the presented models accurately describes the rule — M Students (FK) : 1 Teacher. (Every M:1 *can* be modeled as a M:M with restriction, although this is not a god description.) I suspect this M:1 rule, and resulting model, is likely going to be an issue with the overall design..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two provided options are not equivalent. The first option is the many-to-many relation (every student can have many teachers and every teacher can have many students) while the second option represents the one-to-many relation (every student can have only one teacher).

So, these two data schemes solve different problems.

But if you want to talk about performance, you shouldn't feel much difference on such limits if implemented properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
This is just an example of my real issue. My code is much bigger than this I don't want to start copying everything. Let's say that every student can have only one teacher and a teacher can have multiple students. What is better, 1 or 2?

Best

Comment: If every student can have only one teacher then, of course, you don't need many-to-many relation that creates an intermediate table in the database and lead to extra joins.

So, in general, second solution is better in this case.

Comment: Second choice is better even If every time to get the students of a teacher I have to filter around 100 student out of 1M?

Thanks

Comment: And please if you have a third better solution suggest it. 
Thanks!

Comment: @OsamaAbuhamdan There are no benefits in many-to-many relations, so, yes, the second option is better and the best solution for your case.

Comment: @OsamaAbuhamdan And I suggest you discover the documentation, especially about using a foreign key in Django (you can get students of the teacher by `teacher.students` if you specify the corresponding [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in the `ForeignKey`) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) (it can be helpful for you to increase performance).